# Separating two built equations

Tags: vba, build, ms-word, equation

I have built a form which will build two equations, one with an original equation and one with dynamic variables.  Although both equations are built properly, equation #2 will not build on the next line down.

I have tried using the selection.paragraphs.add between the two equations, but no luck.

Any thoughts?  Thank you for your help.

```
Set objRange1 = Selection.Range
objRange1.Text = "BSA" & "(m" & "^2" & ")" & " = " & ChrW(8730) & "(" & "(" & "Height" & "_(cm)" _
     & " * " & "Weight" & "_(kg)" & ")" & "/3600" & ")"
Set objRange1 = Selection.OMaths.Add(objRange1)
Set objEq1 = objRange1.OMaths(1)
objEq1.BuildUp

Set objRange = Selection.Range
objRange.Text = "BSA" & "(m" & "^2" & ")" & " = " & ChrW(8730) & "(" & "(" & intHeight _
& "_cm" & " * " & dblweight & "_kg" & ")" & "/3600" & ")"
Set objRange = Selection.OMaths.Add(objRange)
Set objeq = objRange.OMaths(1)
objeq.BuildUp
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule it is better to use Ranges than the Selection in Word. For example:

```
Sub Insert2Eqs1()
Dim dblWeight As Double
Dim intHeight As Long
Dim objEq As Word.OMath
Dim objRange As Word.Range
Set objRange = Selection.Range
' You might need to adjust this depending on exactly where you want the 
' equations to appear in relation to the selection
objRange.InsertParagraph
objRange.InsertParagraphBefore
' You now have a range containing two paragraph marks
objRange.Collapse wdCollapseStart
objRange.Text = "BSA" & "(m" & "^2" & ")" & " = " & ChrW(8730) & "(" & "(" & "Height" & "_(cm)" _
     & " * " & "Weight" & "_(kg)" & ")" & "/3600" & ")"
Set objEq = objRange.OMaths.Add(objRange).OMaths(1)
objEq.BuildUp
Set objRange = objEq.Range
objRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
' If you use + 1, you get two equations, one below the other
objRange.Start = objRange.Start + 1
' if you use + 2, you get two equations separated by a paragraph on its own
objRange.Start = objRange.Start + 2
intHeight = 0#
dblWeight = 2.45
objRange.Text = "BSA" & "(m" & "^2" & ")" & " = " & ChrW(8730) & "(" & "(" & intHeight _
& "_cm" & " * " & dblWeight & "_kg" & ")" & "/3600" & ")"
Set objEq = objRange.OMaths.Add(objRange).OMaths(1)
objEq.BuildUp
Set objEq = Nothing
Set objRange = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I appreciate your help.